# How to go back to the beginning of list that is being <Link> through

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a list of lessons the I am pulling from a database. Each one renders a new page. I have Next and Prev buttons the  through each of items passed through props. That works fine, the problem is when the end of the list is reached the app crashed, how do I loop back around to the first Item being rendered?

The prev and next buttons work fine. I tried including a condition in the button such as

```
{if(prev_id > 0 && next_id <= id.length){
//do something
}}
```

```
export default props => {
//These pull the the id from the backend and then I increment or decrement by 1 to link through the pages

const prev_id = Number(props.props.match.params.inid) - 1;
const next_id = Number(props.props.match.params.inid) + 1;

useEffect(() => {
    getLessonTitles(id);
    getLessonData(props.props.match.params.inid);
  }, [props.props.match.params]);

<div>
        <button type="button">
          <Link to={"/lesson/" + id + "/" + prev_id}>PREV</Link>
        </button>
        <button type="button">
          <Link to={"/lesson/" + id + "/" + next_id}>CONTINUE</Link>
        </button>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Check if next_id exist, if not next_id should be equal to first I’d, do the same for prev_id

Comment: Would that be inline in the <Link>?

Comment: How do you know that you're reached the end of the pages? Do you have a static number or array that your component is aware of?

Comment: It is set up as a list of Id's on the backend. I'm not sure how to check if I'm at the end or not

Comment: I see, I've written you a solution below that should give you some insight, let me know if that helps.

Comment: It's awesome, Only thing is im not using Classes in my app, but I can transfer it over to props

Comment: Oh nice! yeah it should be very similar. Let me know if you have any questions, and do please consider marking as solution :)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you set-up your Routes and data-flow. In any case, the component that contains your buttons needs to know just how many items there are in the list. That's really the best way to configure the pagination logic.

Consider an example like this with working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-using-render-prop-oznvu

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Lesson from "./Lesson";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    lessonData: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    //fetch data and set-state here. Will use static list as an example
    const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        description: "Math"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        description: "Science"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        description: "Art"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        description: "English"
      }
    ];

    this.setState({
      lessonData: data
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={props => <Dashboard data={this.state.lessonData} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/lesson/:id"
          render={props => {
            const id = props.match.params.id;
            const data = this.state.lessonData.find(lesson => lesson.id == id);

            return (
              <Lesson
                {...props}
                selected={data}
                lengthOfDataSet={this.state.lessonData.length}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

When the user navigates to the `Lesson` path, we will pass in a prop to the rendered `Lesson` component, the prop contains the number of lesson items retrieved from our data-set (using a static list for example). Additionally, we will use `props.match.params.id` to find the corresponding item in our data-set, and pass that item as a prop as well.

**Lesson.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Lesson = props => {
  const {
    selected,
    lengthOfDataSet,
    match: {
      params: { id }
    }
  } = props;

  const createButtons = () => {
    const prevLinkId = id == 1 ? lengthOfDataSet : parseInt(id) - 1;
    const nextLinkId = id < lengthOfDataSet ? parseInt(id) + 1 : 1;

    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button>
          <Link to={`/lesson/${prevLinkId}`}>Prev</Link>
        </button>
        <button type="button">
          <Link to={`/lesson/${nextLinkId}`}>Next</Link>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  if (!selected) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Back to home</Link>
        <h4>Id: {selected.id}</h4>
        <h4>Description: {selected.description}</h4>
        <div>{createButtons()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

In the `Lesson` component, we can use the props passed to configure our Prev button and Next button logic.

For the Prev button, if the current id is 1, then clicking it would redirect you to a path using the last item in the dataset, otherwise go to previous item.

For the Next button, if the current id is less than the prop (lengthOfDataSet), then clicking it will go to the next item, otherwise go back to the beginning of the set.